# Parse failed when provided string is more than 9 on days

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to turn string to datetime.

```
try{
    dateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Parse(dateData).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}catch (Exception err)
{
    TraceLog.WriteException(err);
    dateValue = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

When the datetime is in "01/Nov/2019" it didn't throw any error. You can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf1hB.png)

if it in "30/Nov/2019", it throw string was not recognized. You can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUR2u.png)

The reason i want use ToString because DateTime.Parse will return the value in this "MM/dd/yyyy" format. For example 11/1/2019, in web it will show as 11 Jan 2019 which i don't want. I already find bunch of solution for few days everywhere but still not work.

Comment: Use ParseExact instead of Parse, so you can better control how the date is parsed.

Comment: Ask youselves - When you Parse a string to Date how would the code know the format of the date? If your string is dd/MMM/yyyy format, you need to tell the code to Parse the date using this format. This is why 1 Nov is become 11 Jan for you. May be look at ParseExact

Comment: You are taking a string (`dateData`), parsing it to a DateTime, converting it back to a string of a specific format, and then calling `Convert.ToDateTime` to convert it back to a DateTime. You're going around the block one too many times. Use `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`. Definitely skip the ToString call and the Convert call

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I did it just now. It still return "string was not recognized". The format is in "dd/MMM/yyyy". For the day that have single digit "01/Nov/2019" it work but not with "10/Nov/2019"

Comment: Show your ParseExact code, please.

Comment: @jayDD2 - Here's mine that works. var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("30/Nov/2019", "dd/MMM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);   (May be use TryParseExact instead of this - so that you dont have an exception for incorrect date)

Comment: @John By using this 'DateTime.ParseExact(dateData, "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)' , the datevalue will be in MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @jayDD2 `dd/MMM/yyyy` is the format of `dateData`. A `DateTime` object stores the full datetime value _only as_ ticks (a `long` value - see the `Ticks` property), and as such has no formatting by itself. The only time you get a formatted value is when you call `.ToString()` (or in the debugger display, which does this for you).

Comment: @jayDD2 - You are seeing that format - probably because that's the Culture/Windows format for your machine in regional settings. First thing we have solved is parsing string to a datetime object. In the DateTime object - verify the Day & Month values. Next use your: dtObj.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")   --- to reformat date into this format.

Answer (score 0):

DateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateData.Trim()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)